# how to write One to One mapping using Xml , in java?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, mapping

how to write one-to-one  mapping using xml,for the below class ?
            in account table customerId has to come.first one is Account class 
            and second class is customer class.

```
public class Account {
        private int customerId;
        private int accountNumber;
        private double balance;
        private String typeOfAccount;
        private Customer customer;
    }


    public class Customer {
        private int customerID;
        private String name;
        private String email;
        private String phoneNumber;

    }
```

Comment: @OneToOne from hibernate. Did you google?

Comment: without annotation..

Comment: <one-to-one> .. again you can first try to do some research

Comment: am not getting? i want  customer.hbm.xml and Account.hbm.xml...(only xml no annotation)..

Comment: Look in [an example for one-to-one mapping in XML](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/)